# Apache mod evasive leads to permission denied of index.php

Tags: apache, security, module, access-denied

For security reasons I installed the apache modules security and evasive.
No I get sometimes the Error

Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /index.php on this server.

The logfile of apache shows me:
[Tue May 12 14:42:32.825039 2015] [evasive20:error] [pid 27443] [client 192.168.32.22:51305] client denied by server configuration: /var/www/test/index.php, referer: http://test.domain.local/index.php

I know it is important to secure Apache Webserver. But this error makes qualified working not possible. How can I prevent from this error?
If I deactive the module with a2dismod evasive, the error does not come up.

Thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Did you set up the limit rate for URL request ?
Try to add this into your apache2.conf

```
DOSHashTableSize 3097
DOSPageCount 5
DOSSiteCount 50
DOSPageInterval 2
DOSSiteInterval 2
DOSBlockingPeriod 10
```

DOSPageCount is the number limit for requesting a URL. DOSPageInterval is the time limit for request a URL. Here for example you can request 5time a URL within 2seconds.

There's an article with a guy having the same problem, here it is if you want more information
http://www.techtutorials.net/articles/introduction_to_apache_mod_evasive.html

Comment: My settings were different - DOSPageCount=2, DOSPageInterval=1, DOSSiteInterval=1. I updated the settings to your recommendation and now, the failure seems to be gone. Thank you for the hint!

Answer (score 0):

The **"evasive20: error client denied by server configuration"** error message is generated by the Apache web server when it denies access to a client due to an evasion attempt. This message is usually produced by the mod_evasive module, which is a security module for Apache that provides basic protection against DoS (Denial of Service) and DDoS (Distributed Denial of Service) attacks.

To resolve the "evasive20: error client denied by server configuration" error, you need to either adjust the configuration of the mod_evasive module or whitelist the client's IP address so that it is no longer blocked. Here are some common steps to resolve this error:

- **Check the mod_evasive configuration:** The first step is to check the
  mod_evasive configuration to make sure that it is configured to block
  clients in a way that is appropriate for your needs. The
  configuration file is typically located at
  /etc/httpd/conf.d/mod_evasive.conf or
  /etc/apache2/mods-available/mod_evasive.conf.
- **Whitelist the client's IP address:** You can add the client's IP
  address to the mod_evasive whitelist to prevent it from being
  blocked. This can be done by adding the following line to the
  mod_evasive configuration file:

  ```
   DOSHashTableSize    3097
   DOSPageCount        10
   DOSSiteCount        50
   DOSPageInterval     1
   DOSSiteInterval     1
   DOSBlockingPeriod   10
   DOSWhitelist 192.168.32.22
   DOSEmailNotify      somone@gmail.com
   DOSSystemCommand    "su - someuser -c '/sbin/... %s ...'"
   DOSLogDir           "/var/log/apache2/"
  ```
- **Modify the request rate threshold:** The mod_evasive module blocks
  clients that make too many requests in a short amount of time. You
  can adjust the threshold for blocking clients by modifying the
  DOSPageCount and DOSSiteCount parameters in the mod_evasive
  configuration file.
- **Restart the Apache server:** After making changes to the mod_evasive
  configuration, you need to restart the Apache server for the changes
  to take effect.

These are some common steps to resolve the "evasive20: error client denied by server configuration" error, but the exact solution will depend on your specific configuration and setup.